# Migrating From Parse To Azure's DocumentDB

Tags: azure, parse-platform, azure-cosmosdb

I'm currently in the process of migrating a live production mobile application from Parse to Azure using the Migration Tool provided by the good folk at Parse, however I'm getting stuck on the "Synch Phase".

I'm getting all green lines indicating a successful transfer of the data, however when the migration tool is checking for any new writes, it fails with the following error:

"There was a problem with the migration."

Parse documentation doesn't have any information on the above, so I would appreciate your help!

[image: Error Received]

I'm running my Azure server and Document DB instances on the S3 (Standard: Large) with Auto scaling, and the Document DB implementation is on Pricing Tier S3 (THROUGHPUT (RU/s) 2500)

Comment: Hello David,
Have you successfully migrated your app DB from parse to Azure?

Answer (score 0):

There is a default preview limit of 10 collections.  If you have more than that, please email askdocdb [AT] Microsoft to request a limit increase.

Comment: @dan - how did you create the documentdb account? the Parse-specific docdb accounts are limited to 10 collections, I believe. And your migration is attempting to deal with 14 classes.

Comment: @DavidMakogon I emailed into the above email address and the person responding said that they increased my limit. I can't see in the portal if it was increased thou! I've deleted the database since, as after the first fail (after the bug update + increase in collections) I was getting another migration error "Database not empty"

Answer (score 0):

This is the document you need to refer:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/azure-welcomes-parse-developers/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.